# How to choose a set of unique random numbers (no duplicates) using the jQuery.inArray method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random, unique

This is a Javascript / jQuery question:

I'm trying to generate six unique random numbers between 1 and 21 (no duplicates), using the **jQuery.inArray** method. Those six numbers will then be used to select six .jpg files from a group named logo1.jpg through logo21.jpg.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
<div id="client-logos"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

Show = 6; // Number of logos to show
TotalLogos = 21; // Total number of logos to choose from
FirstPart = '<img src="/wp-content/client-logos/logo';
LastPart = '.jpg" height="60" width="120" />';
r = new Array(Show); // Random number array

var t=0;
for (t=0;t<Show;t++)
   {
      while ( jQuery.inArray(x,r)
         {
            var x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * TotalLogos);
         });
      r[t] = x;
      var content = document.getElementById('client-logos').innerHTML;
      document.getElementById('client-logos').innerHTML = content + FirstPart + r[t] + LastPart;
   }

</script>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you sure that's right?  It looks like a syntax error around that "while" loop to me - there's a missing close-paren ...

Comment: Also, it looks like you update exactly the same element over and over again with each random image.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: @Pointy: he sets the innerHTML to the `content` variable before re-assigning.  @Shaun: As an aside, it's generally bad practice to modify innerHTML inside a loop.  Generate your HTML string in the loop, but don't assign it to the element until after the loop ends.

Comment: @Andy E oh I see - well that will work but it's a bad idea for other reasons, as you note :-)

Comment: @Shaun a better way to do this is the Fisher-Yates (or Knuth) shuffle - there's [a Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) on the topic that's pretty understandable. You'd build an array of numbers 1 to 21, shuffle it, then pick the first 6 from the list.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I really appreciate all of your input. @gonchuki posted a great solution below, which I ended up using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have a few issues there:

- variables in the global window scope
- an array declared with the `new` keyword instead of a literal
- trying to use variables before declaring them
- jQuery.inArray being incorrectly used ([inArray returns a number](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/), not `true` or `false`)
- inefficient code with a `while` loop which theoretically could lead to an infinite loop

now, the second combined with the third is the main issue here, as the first time you test for `x` in the array it is `undefined` (you are only defining it inside the `if` with a `var` statement, so the x is at first undefined) and thus it matches the first element in the array (which is `undefined` as you declared `r` with `new Array(6)`) and the inArray function returns 1, which leads to an infinite loop.

There are several things you could do to patch that code, but I think a complete rewrite with a different approach might be better and requires no jQuery at all.

This modified version of your code should work fine:

```
var Show = 6, // Number of logos to show
    TotalLogos = 21, // Total number of logos to choose from
    FirstPart = '<img src="/wp-content/client-logos/logo',
    LastPart = '.jpg" height="60" width="120" />',
    array = [], // array with all avaiilable numbers
    rnd, value, i,
    logosElement = document.getElementById('client-logos');

for (i = 0; i < TotalLogos; i++) { // arrays are zero based, for 21 elements you want to go from index 0 to 20.
  array[i] = i + 1;
}

for (i = 0; i < Show; i++) { // pick numbers
  rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length); 
  value = array.splice(rnd,1)[0]; // remove the selected number from the array and get it in another variable

  logosElement.innerHTML += (FirstPart + value + LastPart);
}
```

To explain a little what I did here:

- initialize an array with all the possible values you have (numbers 1 to 21)
- run a loop only as many times as numbers you want to pick.
- generate a random number from 0 to the maximum index available in your numbers array
- remove the number at that index from the array using splice, and then use it to create the string for the innerHTML call ([splice returns the elements removed from the array as another new array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)).
- additionally, the `logosElement` variable is cached at the beginning so you only do a single DOM lookup for the element.

There are more ways that code can be rewritten and even cleaned up, but I figured this would be the cleanest way to help you with your issue (and it's cross-browser safe! no need to add jQuery unless you need it for another functionality)

Comment: Wow! Works perfectly and you explained it extremely well. Thank you a thousand times.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Initial number
var x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * TotalLogos);

// Keep searching until a unique number is found
while ($.inArray(x, r) > -1) {
    x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * TotalLogos);
}

// If it's unique, set it
r[t] = x;
```

Comment: Thanks Ed! I ended up going with @gonchuki's solution, but appreciate your response.

Comment: This can be an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

The immediately obvious reason it's not working, other than the extra closing parenthesis after your `while` loop, is a slight misunderstanding on how `$.inArray` method works.  `$.inArray` returns the first index of a matched value in the array, or `-1` if it's not found.  `-1` is a "truthy" value, meaning your `while` loop will continue execution if the random number *isn't in the array*.  In fact, it will continue execution until it finds the number at the 0th location of the array.

In order to fix that particular problem, you need to check that it's greater than -1, as well as setting the `x` var to a random number before the loop:

```
var x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * TotalLogos);

while ($.inArray(x, r) > -1) {
    x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * TotalLogos);
}
r[t] = x;
```

In the comment replies to your question, Pointy also mentions the Fisher-Yates Shuffle.  That method of shuffling might give you better distribution than the approach you're using.

Comment: This can be an infinite loop