# jQuery cycle plugin - display multiple images from same set w/ no duplicates

Tags: jquery, image, random, cycle

**Setup:**

I have a set of ~20 images.  I want to display 6 of them at a time and use the jQuery Cycle plugin to randomly rotate in different images from the set.  I've cobbled together a solution where I call the Cycle plugin 6 different times and have every image listed in each of the 6 div's. The current solution is roughly based on [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143401/how-to-choose-a-set-of-unique-random-numbers-no-duplicates-using-the-jquery-in).

**Problem:**

I don't want duplicate images to show.  Right now there will frequently be 2 or even 3 duplicates showing at the same time.  This looks rather silly!  I'm assuming this would involve some kind of re-writing of the array on the fly based on what image is showing (is there a way to tell?) but i'm really stuck on how to go about it.

Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

**Current Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var NumImages = 20, // Number of logos to show
        FirstPart = '<img src="/DEV/demo/images/',
        LastPart = '.jpg" height="50" width="100" />',
        array = ['bali.sm',          'disney.sm', 'fisherprice.sm',
                 'fruit.of.loom.sm', 'gerber.sm', 'hamilton.beach.sm',
                 'hotwheels.sm',     'igloo.sm',  'magnavox.sm',
                 'matchbox.sm',      'mohawk.sm', 'playtex.sm',
                 'purina.sm',        'rca.sm',    'remington.sm',
                 'rubbermaid.sm',    'shark.sm',  'sony.sm',
                 'sunbeam.sm',       'tonka.sm'], // array with all image names
        rnd, value, i;

    for (i = 0; i < NumImages; i++) { // pick numbers
        rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length); 
        value = array.splice(rnd,1)[0]; // remove the selected number from the array and get it in another variable

        document.getElementById('pic1').innerHTML += (FirstPart + value + LastPart);
        document.getElementById('pic2').innerHTML += (FirstPart + value + LastPart);
        document.getElementById('pic3').innerHTML += (FirstPart + value + LastPart);
        document.getElementById('pic4').innerHTML += (FirstPart + value + LastPart);
        document.getElementById('pic5').innerHTML += (FirstPart + value + LastPart);
        document.getElementById('pic6').innerHTML += (FirstPart + value + LastPart);
    }
    $("#pic1").cycle({ fx: 'fade', speed: 2000, timeout: 28000, random: 1, delay: -15000 });
    $("#pic2").cycle({ fx: 'fade', speed: 2000, timeout: 28000, random: 1, delay: -10000 });
    $("#pic3").cycle({ fx: 'fade', speed: 2000, timeout: 28000, random: 1, delay: -5000 });
    $("#pic4").cycle({ fx: 'fade', speed: 2000, timeout: 28000, random: 1, delay: 0 });
    $("#pic5").cycle({ fx: 'fade', speed: 2000, timeout: 28000, random: 1, delay: 5000 });
    $("#pic6").cycle({ fx: 'fade', speed: 2000, timeout: 28000, random: 1, delay: 10000 });
});
```

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-8-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100) might help?

Answer (score 0):

I might construct a temporary array to store the numbers I've randomly generated, and then check it each time:

```
var tmparray = [];
for (var i=0; i<NumImages; i++) { // pick numbers
    rnd = -1; 
    while (tmparray.indexOf(rnd) == -1) {
        rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length); 
    }
    tmparray.push(rnd);
    value = array.splice(rnd,1)[0];

    ...

} // end for
```

Comment: ...but see http://stackoverflow.com/q/143847/901048 for details about using `array.indexOf()`